# Data is not inserting in my Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase, I am going through a tutorial, and practicing the Firebase connectivity. I want to add a data into my Firebase. But somehow it's not adding. I don't know what's the problem. Firebase is connected Successfully. 
Here's my main activity.

```
package com.example.sayan.appfire;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button msendData;
    private Firebase mRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mRef = new Firebase("https://appfire-713c6.firebaseio.com/");
        msendData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendData);


        msendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Firebase mRefChild = mRef.child("name");
                mRefChild.setValue("Sayan");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: follow this step by step http://www.inheritx.com/integrate-firebase-database-android/

Comment: You could debug the error using a CompletionListener: `mRefChild.setValue("Sayan", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
  Log.d("MainActivity", databaseError.toException())});`

Comment: @Neeraj my app is getting crashed after clicking the button. I've done the changes you've told me.

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: How to check my crash log ? @Aditya. in the Logcat Error part, it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this way to perform operation on firebase database

```
private void createUser(String name, String email) {
        // TODO
        // In real apps this userId should be fetched
        // by implementing firebase auth
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
        }

        User user = new User(name, email);

        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);

        addUserChangeListener();
    }
```

For more check this out :

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabase =         
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("tasks").push().setValue(firebaseData, new 
    DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference 
    databaseReference) {
    //Problem with saving the data
    if (databaseError != null) {

    } else {
            //Data uploaded successfully on the server

           }

        }
});
```

Comment: else part to declare insert dta variable in data base